# Getting to grips with regular expressions in grep

Tags: r, string, grepl

I am struggling to understand how to use `grep` and similar to extract strings that I need.
My strings are of the pattern `"1899-12-31 17:20:00 UTC"`. I want to remove all before and including the first space, and remove `" UTC"`. The output on this example is `17:20:00`. How do I do that with base r functions like grep or gsub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R option using `gsub`

```
> gsub("^(\\S+\\s)|(\\s\\S+)$", "", "1899-12-31 17:20:00 UTC")
[1] "17:20:00"
```

where

- `^(\\S+\\s)` searches the substring (no space included) from the head till the first space
- `(\\S+\\s)$` searches the substring from the last space till the tail of the string

---

Another option is using `scan`

```
> scan(text = "1899-12-31 17:20:00 UTC", what = "", quiet = TRUE)[2]
[1] "17:20:00"
```

---

A **super genius** idea from @akrun's comment is using `as.POSIXct`

```
> format(as.POSIXct("1899-12-31 17:20:00 UTC"), "%H:%M:%S")
[1] "17:20:00"
```